# Thief, exponential reward, optimal strategy

Tags: probability, optimization, dynamic-programming

A thief robs a house every night. His profit each night is independent of others, and is a random variable with $Exp(1/\lambda)$ distribution. Every night, there is a probability $0<q<1$ that he is caught and has to return his total profit. What is an optimal strategy for when to stop in order to maximise his total expected profit?

If anyone can help me out with this then that is very good!!

Comment: out of curiousity, does he know q?

Comment: yes he knows the value of q. I have tried to use the dynamic programming equation, but am not able to get it to make sense.

Comment: I get that if the expected winings were constant or at least the average one were constant, he should stop when $v/p > 1/q-1$ where q is the probability of getting caught, v is the current winnings, and p is the expected average winnings each game. I have issues solving the problem fully, however, as I am not sure how that random distribution works. Either way, he needs to stop if the expected earning times the probability of success exheeds the already won money times the probability of failure. (assuming if he losses he can't play again)

Comment: The random distribution works in the following way: If X is a $Exp(1/\lambda)$ random variable, then the expected value $E(X) = \lambda$. Does this help. How were you able to get the above result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thief wakes up and takes a look at his finances:

He has robbed enough houses to earn V dollars.
If he robs another house he expects to win $\lambda$ dollars.
He has, however a probability q of getting caught and losing all V dollars he already won.

Therefore: he expects his money to change by $E = \lambda*(1-q)-Vq$.

If $V/\lambda>\frac{1-q}{q}$ then his potential earning (E) from robbing a house will actually be a negative reducing his maximum potential winnings so he shouldn't do it.  His predicted winnings, however, haven't been determined like this and he will earn less than $\lambda\frac{1-q}{q}$ on average as he has a chance to lose before reaching that point.

Answer (score 2):

His expected gain from the next burglary is $\lambda (1-q)$ while if he already has $V$ (matching kaine's comment) then his expected loss is $Vq$. So, assuming he takes nothing else into account, he should stop when $$ \lambda (1-q) \le Vq$$ which could be written as $\lambda \le V\frac{q}{1-q}$ or $V \ge \lambda \frac{1-q}{q}$ or $q \ge \frac{\lambda}{\lambda + V}$ or as kaine's comment has it $\frac{V}{\lambda} \ge \frac{1-q}{q}$ or  $\frac{\lambda}{V} \ge \frac{q}{1-q}$ .   The last expression can be interpreted as a statement about comparing the *odds* of being caught with the expected proportional gain of the next attempt.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very clear explanation